# Crash for second view object's name assign

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xib

I am new to Xamarin and MVVMCross. So I have created 2 views. Login and Register. I have a button on Login to goto Register view and I am going there by this code in the Login's ViewModel:

```
// method when user tap register button
public IMvxCommand NavigateRegister
{
    get { return new MvxCommand(() => ShowViewModel<RegisterViewModel>()); }
}
```

It works ok the Register Page opens well. But once I assign Name for a single object on Register view (a textEdit), the app crash when I tap on the Register button.

Below is the error msg:

> Xamarin.iOS: Received unhandled ObjectiveC exception:
>   NSUnknownKeyException [
>   setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key regNameEdit.

**EDIT:**
More details: I already assigned the name (see pic below), but still crash:
[image]

And the view also been assigned to its Class "CreateAccount". But I am noticing the class declaration has "partial" darkened out in the "`public partial class CreateAccount : MvxViewController`" line. That's the only noticeable difference btw this class and the first one.

```
using MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext;
using MvvmCross.iOS.Views;

namespace MyApp.iOS.Views
{
    public partial class CreateAccount : MvxViewController
    {
        public CreateAccount() : base("CreateAccount", null)
        {
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

            Title = "Register";

            var set = this.CreateBindingSet<CreateAccount, Core.ViewModels.CreateAccountModel>();
            set.Bind(regNameEdit).To(vm => vm.NameStr);
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
        {
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
        }
    }
}
```

The Bind(regNameEdit) also is an error (not detecting the textedit still)

Answer (score 1):

This usually means that the a control is not defined in the View/ViewController class in your case the `regNameEdit`.

Make sure you created the back Property for this Edit and that the class assigned to the XIB is the one containing this property.

If you are using Xamarin Studio Designer you create the back property selecting the UIControl in the XIB/StoryBoard and setting a name, then enter.

[image]

This will create a property with the name you specified accessible in the ViewController.

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();

    this.MyUITextField.Text = string.Empty;
}
```

**UPDATE**

**When using Storyboard:**

Try this: Remove the name from the TextField and also remove the name from the ViewController class, then clean your project and rebuild. Re-add the class to the ViewController but when doing it click over the yellow icon in the bottom, there put the name and hit enter. Continue with the TextField, select it put the name and hit enter.

**UPDATE # 2**

**When using XIBs**
When you create the ViewController from the menu, Xamarin Studio will create both the ViewController class and the XIB file and will associate one with the other so here you don't have to do anything else to link them.

For the TextField you will need to do it adding the name as previously indicated.

Try this: Remove the name of the UITextField and save and clean/rebuild the project then add the name and hit enter.

Something you can do to verify if there's any problem, double click on the button in the XIB and this should take you to the ViewController class to create a method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. I actually already did that but the crash still occur. I added more details to my question if you want to take a look.

Comment: I think I am missing something basic here. I didn't realize there is a storyboard and a viewcontroller to the project. Right now I design everything in a xib. Have no idea how viewcontroller link to the firstview.xib.

Comment: Ok. I double click on the btn on second xib, but nothing happens. What could be the problem?

Comment: Ok I found out the problem. Since I am using Mvx, the view class namespace is MyApp.iOS.Views, but the view designer class was MyApp.iOS. What i did is change the namespace following the view class namespace, and everything now works. I appreciate your answer because somehow it leads me to solve my problem. TQ v.much and have a nice day!